# MSBuild.exe is deleting my NLog.config file when I start debugging (F5) VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, nlog

This is a weird error, take a look at this:

[image: Error]

This is the issue: I'm using VS2015 to build a solution. This solution is composed out of 3 projects which need to be run (but the error happens even if I run just one out of those three). They all share a library which references another one (SharpRUDP) which uses NLog for some logging.

So far so good. Watch the image: When I choose Rebuild, it copies the NLog.config file to the output folder (which is a network drive Z: pointing to a locally shared folder). When I press F5, the file gets deleted. WHY?

My code does not have any File.delete lines regarding .config files or anything like that. It's driving me crazy. I have set up a github branch here in case anyone want to take a look... just clone, change output folder, compile and run. It doesn't matter if it throws exceptions or whatever, just press F5 and watch the file disappear. I'm sad :( :

Github: https://github.com/darkguy2008/FreeRDC/tree/v5-nlogissue

Happy father's day btw. Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: appreciate the effort, but the github project doesn't even have an NLog.config so cannot reproduce..

Comment: Thanks for giving it a look :). It does, it's referencing SharpRUDP and the NLog is here -> https://github.com/darkguy2008/SharpRUDP/tree/nlogissue/SharpRUDP/SharpRUDP I kind of fixed it by copying the nlog.config file any of the FreeRDC projects, but it makes no sense to have two config files in the project, it's confusing for newcomers.

Comment: I used 'git clone git clone git@github.com:darkguy2008/FreeRDC.git', then 'git submodule init' then 'git submodule update' and the NLog.config is not there..

Comment: Well I'm not a git wiz, I hate the console, so all I use is GitKraken and it automatically does all that. The NLog file is there in the link I put, I dunno really if the repo is initializing the submodule or not, but the file is there. I can't be of much help there, sorry :(

Comment: doesn't matter what you use, the problem is that the commit your submodule points to doesn't have NLog.config: https://github.com/darkguy2008/SharpRUDP/tree/master/SharpRUDP/SharpRUDP - if GitKraken somehow gets an Nlog.config then it's not behaving correctly. Or, you are not using the same branch as linked to in your question

Comment: It's an old post, but is there any update on this issue? I have the same problem!